# Split Landing Page being moved to the left side

Tags: javascript, html, css

`enter code here`So I am currently following the tutorial of Traversy Media on how to build a Split Landing Page and I came across a problem where it does not want to shift to the left side. at 20:50 in the video, he shows us what the example should look like and my code is not matching up to his for some reason. I've looked over it multiple times and cannot find out why my page is not shifting over to the left side as it is supposed to be. It would be beyond ideal if someone could help me figure this out :)

```js
const left = document.querySelector('.left');
const right = document.querySelector('.right');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');


left.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    container.classList.add('hover-left');
});

left.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
    container.classList.remove('hover-left');
});

right.addEventListener('mousenter', ()=>{
    container.classList.add('hover-right');
});

right.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
    container.classList.remove('hover-right');
});
```

```css
:root{
    --container-bg-color: #333;
    --left-bg-color: rgba(223, 39, 39, 0.7);
    --left-button-hover-color: rgba(161, 11, 11. 0.3);
    --right-bg-color: rgba(43,43,43,0.8);
    --right-button-hover-color: rgba(92,92,92,0.3);
    --hover-width: 75%;
    --other-width: 25%;
    --speed: 1000ms;
}

html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1{
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.button{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    height: 2.5rem;
    padding-top: 1.3rem;
    width: 15rem;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    border: #fff solid 0.2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.split.left .button:hover{
    background-color: var(--left-button-hover-color);
    border-color: var(--left-button-hover-color);
}

.split.right .button:hover{
    background-color: var(--right-button-hover-color);
    border-color: var(--right-button-hover-color);
}


.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--container-bg-color);
}


.split{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.split.left{
    left: 0;
    background: url('/img/design.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}


.split.left:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--left-bg-color);
}


.split.right{
    right: 0;
    background: url("#") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.split.right:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--right-bg-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Split Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styless.css">
</head>
<body> 
   
   <div class="container">
       <div class="split-left">
           <h1>The Beast</h1>
           <a href="#" class="button">Learn More</a>
       </div>
       <div class="split-right">
           <h1>The Man</h1>
           <a href="#" class="button">Learn More</a>
       </div>
   </div>
   
   
   <script src="main.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this at all - you can do it all with CSS's built-in interactivity features.

Comment: Thanks for writing back! I appreciate the comment, but my main concern would be why the code is not shifting the words and the button over to the left side??

Comment: I didn't check in detail, but seems that there is no .left and .right class in the DOM (am I missing it?). Also, in the CSS file, I can't find the hover-left and hover right. Would that be the problem?

Comment: Thanks for writing back to me Kenny! The hover-left/right should be in the ":root" of CSS. and as far as the ".left/right" I have a "split.left" in the code. That is shown running in his code before he even put in the .right code in. If that makes sense lol

Comment: I just updated the code snippet. It now has the right-side code in it, and is still not responding :/